how to add logic to zap logger's .Error() method?
if there is a log like this
logger, _ := zap.NewProduction()
logger.Error("hello")

i want the .Error() to also do other stuff for example sending logs with a specific message to an email, sending error only logs to a telegram bot, etc
i've tried hooks but i dont get access to full fields
    core := zapcore.RegisterHooks(logger.Core(), func(e zapcore.Entry) error {
        if e.Message == "[Recovery from panic]" {
            teleBot.SendMessageToAllChatIDs(fmt.Sprintf(
                "log_name: %s\nlevel: %s\nts: %s\nmsg: %s\nstack: %s",
                e.LoggerName,
                e.Level.String(),
                e.Time.Format(time.RFC1123),
                e.Message,
                e.Stack,
            ))
        }
        return nil
    })


you probably don't want to do that. stick to the single responsibility principle and rather send the message on the recovery event rather than from within your logger

You can wrap logger.Error to a new function. Inside this function, do all you want to do besides logging.

You can define a new struct with *zap.Logger embedded and create custom error methods on that, while also retaining all of its methods.
type Logger struct {
    *zap.Logger
}

func NewLogger() *Logger {
    logger, _ := zap.NewProduction()
    return &Logger{
        logger,
    }
}

func (l *Logger) CustomError(msg string, fields ...zapcore.Field) {
    l.Error(msg, fields...)
    // custom logic
}

func main() {
    logger := NewLogger()
    logger.Error("hello")
    logger.CustomError("hello")
}

